# puppet Could not retrieve fact selinux

Tags: debian, puppet, facter

I have a puppet node that runs this on cron:

```
/usr/bin/puppet agent --onetime --no-daemonize
```

I worked fine in debian Wheezy, but after upgrading to Debian Jessie, I get this message on the node every time puppet agent runs:

```
Could not retrieve fact='selinux_current_mode', resolution='<anonymous>': undefined method `each_line' for nil:NilClass
Could not retrieve fact='selinux_config_mode', resolution='<anonymous>': undefined method `each_line' for nil:NilClass
Could not retrieve fact='selinux_config_policy', resolution='<anonymous>': undefined method `each_line' for nil:NilClass
```

I narrowed down to facter but I don't know how to get rid of this. I checked puppet master not to have this, as seen in another post:

```
facts_terminus = inventory_active_record
```

It was not there, so I don't know what else to check. The node puppet release is 3.7.2-4, and the puppet server is puppetmaster 3.7.5-1puppetlabs1

Any hints ? Thank you.

Comment: Probably some of your puppet manifest makes use of selinux facts from facter. Could you possibly ensure that selinux on your machine is enabled ? Just check the value of selinux fact. More about selinux in facter: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/2.2/core_facts.html#selinux

Comment: What version of facter are you using?

Comment: Are you seeing those messages on the master or on the node running the agent?

Comment: The messages are on the node.

Comment: The version of facter is: 2.2.0

Comment: I was checking the selinux in the client as kkamilpl suggested. None of my own manifests use it, I am not sure if there is some global manifest or something that may use it. I followed the link about core_facts and /selinux/enforce is 0 and /proc/self/attr/current is unconfined. I am not sure if I am using it, anyway I'd like to find out what manifest is trigging this error and remove it. I didn't find any file like "*facter*" in /etc. How can I find facter config to disable this ?

Comment: Seeing as this was caused by the Jessie update, could it be that you switched to Ruby `2.0`? Do all your facts support that? Does your version of Facter?

Comment: Thank you Felix Frank, I checked this is ruby 2.1.5 , facter 2.2.0-1. All from jessie apt sources. I am not aware I was using facts myself, I am just starting with puppet. I commented all the includes in the node to find out which one is triggering the warning. With no includes it keeps showing the message, so it must be something missing in the node.